# Ajuda com script para traçar rotas

Tags: shell-script

Estou criando um script parecido ao tracerouce, quando eu digito um IP ele traça a rota de chegar no destino final, mas quando a rota chega ao destino, o while ainda continua, como eu corrijo esse problema, parar quando chegar no destino final?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite um IP: "; read ip
count=1;
while [ $count -lt 30 ]; do
    ping $ip -t $count -c 1 | grep ^From | awk '{print $2}'
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            printf 'O salto é: '    
        else
        echo 'Rota Indisponível'
        fi
let count=$count+1;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na variável de retorno '$?', utilizada no desvio condicional. Você está checando o retorno do comando awk, que sempre retorna '0' neste caso, portanto o loop sempre executará até que $count chegue em 30. Você pode validar a saída do ping após o awk, como a alteração no seu script a seguir:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite um IP: "; read ip
count=1;
while [ $count -lt 30 ]; do
  ping $ip -t $count -c 1 | grep ^From | awk '{print $2}' | grep -P '^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      printf 'O salto é: '
    else
      echo 'Rota Indisponível'
      exit
    fi
let count=$count+1;
done
```